# How to get http to https redirection in azure application gateway

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I recently added azure application gateway infront of my 2 app services to enable Web Application Firewall(WAF). I added 2 https listeners with listener type as Multi site and corresponding routing rules for them. I wanted to enable http to https redirection so that whenever user hits the app service endpoint with http protocol it gets redirected to https.

For that I added 2 more listeners with http protocol and Multi site listener type and 2 routing rules. In routing rule, I gave target type as Redirection and set the redirection target to above https listener of same host.

The http to https redirection is not working. In the backend settings I am not overriding host name
[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the same in my environment in portal redirection reflects immediately, Generally in azure portal tends to reflect and changes take effect more quickly than other methods like below:***

Created application gateway and redirect to http to https like below:

Added backend pool with two app service and added Https routing rule with certificate like below:

[image]

Create two listeners with HTTP and HTTPS like below:

[image]

Added another routing rule with HTTP and redirection through listener  target listener as HTTPS listener like below

[image]

You can check the backend status are healthy like below:

[image]

Now, when I check the redirect changes have been redirected immediately like below:

[image]

> My App Gateway is getting updated but there is some delay of indefinite amount of time(1-2 days) to reflect that change.
> Why is it happening?

***Note***: Due to the way Azure updates resources in the background there may be a delay in the deployment of your Azure Application Gateway changes. The propagation and complete application of modifications made using ARM templates frequently take some time. Another thing The caching settings on your browser or network could also be the reason for the delay try to the cache and refresh the page.

You can the  Azure Resource Manager [Activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log?tabs=powershell) that provides detailed information on the status and any error occurs

As well as ensuring that the routing rule points to the correct listener and that the redirection target, listener, and protocol are all listening on the relevant ports, you should additionally increase the priority of the redirection rule.  If the target listener is not configured correctly, the redirection won't work as intended.

Comment: Thanks Imran, One more question, Whose priority should be higher? https or http?

Comment: In general, HTTPS traffic should be given higher priority over HTTP traffic. HTTPS is a more secure protocol and encrypts the data transmitted between the client and the server you can set the HTTPS listener to have a higher priority in the listener configuration. This will ensure that traffic sent to the HTTPS listener is processed before traffic sent to the HTTP listener.

Comment: I found that it is not working on google chrome, but only on Firefox. Not sure what I am missing in my configuration

Comment: If the HTTP to HTTPS redirection is working in Firefox but not in Google Chrome it does't  indicate that your configuration is incorrect. Clear Chrome's cookies and cache to make sure that any old configurations or cached redirects aren't interfering with the redirection. Sometimes, cached data can prevent the browser from following the redirection. try using in inprivate mode  as well

Comment: Chrome has a feature called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) which enforces HTTPS connections for certain websites.it automatically enforce HTTPS connections,bypassing the HTTP to HTTPS redirection Verify the SSL certificate Check any certificate-related issues that might be causing Chrome to reject the redirection.You can use online SSL certificate validation tools to validate.

Comment: I am trying in chrome incognito. Btw it is also not working in edge browser.